# How to create a script automating CMD(command prompt) and line of commands

Tags: shell

I would like to create a shell script that automatically open the CMD and type 2 lines of command

> This is the herierchy
>
> 1. open CMD
> 2. Change directory (cd d:\mydirectory\drivers
> 3. command ( file.exe start -c )

I tried some examples in the existing posts but it has different ways like editing regedit/run at start up..

What I need is to create a executable file wherein if I click it, it will automatically open cmd and type those commands.

I am not also familiar nor knowledgeable in creating shell scripts.

Hope someone will help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to specifically open CMD?

Just create a file, call it `script.sh`, as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd d:\mydirectory\drivers
file.exe start -c
```

Save the script and to make it executable, run `chmod +x script.sh`

Now, you can run it by just clicking on it.

Comment: Thank you for your response... Is there a way to do it in CMD instead of bash? It doesn't work in bash, because I am expecting to open a new cmd window after the last command...

Comment: well, some shell will have to be used, i think

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your help and time. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution already. Thank you very much for your time.

I just put these command (step-2 and 3) in notepad

then save as textfile.cmd